# How to empty a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I don't know what is the syntax for emptying a datagridview. Please help me here is my code.

```
if (cboProduct.SelectedIndex != -1)
    load_variant();
else
    //empty the datagridview
    cboProduct.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

set datasource as null

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

Or

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
```

OR

```
while (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: @Harvey have you try with RemoveAt?

Answer (score 6):

> syntax for emptying a datagridview

Just assign `null` to its [DataSource property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx).

```
yourGridView.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there another way?

Comment: @Harvey maybe you can try `yourGridView.Rows.Clear()` then

Comment: @V4Vendetta I tried that but there is an exception ` Cannot clear this list. `

Comment: @Harvey, what is the problem you are having when assigning null to the datasource ?

Comment: @Harvey since your grid is bound to a list you will have to clear the underlying list but doesn't setting the `Datasource` to null work for you ?

Comment: @Habib No I'm just asking if there's another way.

Comment: @Harvey, its probably the best way for clearing `DataGridView`, not really sure why are you looking for other ways.

Comment: @Habib Yes setting the datasource to null worked but in my case it also erases the column header so for me the `RemoveAt` is better in my  application. Thank you.

Comment: @Harvey, thats a pretty valid point, I guess you should have included that in the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Just set [`DataGridView.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `null`

> Gets or sets the data source that the DataGridView is displaying data
>   for.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

As an alternative (not exactly what `.DataSource = null` does)

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)DataGridView1.DataSource;
if(dt != null)
    dt.Clear();
```

Comment: @Harvey What exception? On where?

Comment: @SonerGönül i guess it need not be a `DataTable` probably a cast exception OP is talking about

Answer (score 1):

You can set its DataSource to null :

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**

```
datagridview1.DataSourse=null;
```

**Approach2:**

```
DataView DV = (DataView)this.SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
DV.Table.Clear();
```

**Approach 3:**

```
datagridview1.DataSource = ""
```

**Approach 4:**

```
datagridview1.Dispose();//Clears gridview with all its properties
```

**Approach 5:**

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("datagridview1").outerHTML = "";
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: It is not a `Gridview` what OP asked..!

Comment: it will get applied to datagridview also

Answer (score 1):

`if (dgView.DataSource == null) return;
((DataTable)dgView.DataSource).Rows.Clear();
((DataTable)dgView.DataSource).Columns.Clear();`

I used this one to clean datagrid view on my window application.

`dgView.DataSource = null` is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Setting the data source to null will also reset all formatting of the `DataGridView`. You can preserve the formatting by creating an empty `DataTable` and setting that as the source.

For example:

```
// Create an empty datatable
DataTable empty = new DataTable();
empty.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
empty.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(myEnum));
empty.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
...

// Clear datagridview
dgv.DataSource = empty;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int nn = yourgridview.Rows.Count;
for (int i=nn; i>1; i--)
{ 
    {
        yourgridview.Rows.RemoveAt(i-2);
    }
}
```